# VSTS Extension - How to get selected suite data from test suites table on loading of custom tab

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I'm developing a VSTS extension in Javascript. In one of my tasks, I develop a custom tab and need to load data on an HTML page on behalf of the selected Test Suite.

How can I get data(like SuiteID, Testplan ID) of the selected Test Suite?

[image: Below is the referense image]